# String outOfBoundsException while using charAt

Tags: java, bukkit

I have the following code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public void changeSkin(String name){
    try {
        URL uuidURL = new URL("https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + name);

        String uuid = new Scanner(uuidURL.openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        uuid = uuid.substring(7, 39);

        System.out.println(uuid); // works

        URL valueURL = new URL("https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/" + uuid + "?unsigned=false");

        String value = new Scanner(valueURL.openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        value = value.replace('"', '!');
        value = value.replaceAll("!value!:!", "*");
        value = value.replaceAll("=!,", "+");
        value = value.substring(value.charAt('*'), value.charAt('+')); // Gives an error outOfBounds: -13

        String signature = new Scanner(valueURL.openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        signature = signature.replaceAll("!signature!:!", "_");
        signature = signature.replaceAll("=!}]}", "~");
        signature = signature.substring(value.charAt('_'), value.charAt('~'));

        System.out.println(signature);
        System.out.println(value);

        //profile.getProperties().put("textures", new Property(value, signature));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

While running it throws and outOfBoundsException: -13

But how can that throw a negative number?

Thanks for any help

Edit: Here is the website: https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/e96ca9800c6c4a1588a2922a02ae1080?unsigned=false

Comment: Try using Minecraft's JSON library for what you are doing, it may help.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are making some kind of minecraft bot or something ... but that's irrelevant.

You are using charAt incorrectly.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)

What you are looking for is indexOf

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with that, it finally worked

Answer (score -1):

You ask for the character position for `'*'` and THEN ask for the position `'+'`. The problem is that the plus is located BEFORE the star in the string, so it's returning a negative number.

To remedy, I would suggest breaking the substring into two lines:

```
    value = value.substring(value.indexOf('*'));
    value = value.substring(0, value.indexOf('+'));
```

Though it may seem irrelevant, breaking it into two lines breaks the string at the first instance of the * and then at the NEXT first instance of the +.